# Use summernote with vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, summernote, rubaxa-sortable

I try to create todo list with next features:

1. sortable items
2. WYSIWYG editor in each item
3. each changes in item's editor store in todos model

I made 1 and 2 but can't make 3. I can only change a title of the first task in tasks array

This is my code

**app.js**

```
Vue.directive('summernote', {
  bind: function() {
    this.editor = $(this.el).summernote({
      airMode: true,
      disableDragAndDrop: true,
      popover: {
        air: [
          ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']]
        ]
      },
      callbacks: {
        onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
          vm.tasks[0].title = contents;
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#todos',

  ready: function (value) {
    Sortable.create(this.$el.firstChild, {
      draggable: 'li',
      animation: 500,
      onUpdate: function(e) {
        var oldPosition = e.item.getAttribute('data-id');
        var newPosition = this.toArray().indexOf(oldPosition);
        vm.tasks.splice(newPosition, 0, vm.tasks.splice(oldPosition, 1)[0]);
      }
    });
  },

  data: {
    tasks: [
      { title: 'First task', done: true },
      { title: 'Second task', done: true },
      { title: 'Third task', done: false }
    ],
    newTask: '',
    editTask: null
  },

  methods: {
    addTask (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.tasks.push({ title: this.newTask, done: false });
      this.newTask = '';
    },

    removeTask (index) {
      this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

**index.html**

```
    <div class="container">
    <div id="todos"><ul class="list-group">
        <li
            v-for="task in tasks"
            class="list-group-item"
            data-id="{{$index}}"
            >
          <span
                @click="task.done = !task.done"
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
                ></span>
                <div v-summernote>{{ task.title }}</div>
          <span @click="removeTask($index)" class="close">&times;</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <form @submit="addTask">
      <input v-model="newTask" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Add some task">
    </form>
    <div v-summernote></div>
    <pre>{{tasks | json}}</pre>
    <pre>{{editor}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I edit and save in each item summernote's content? This is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vborshchov/f5Lhaw2e/19/)

Comment: `vm.tasks[0].title = contents;` this is what you're saving, right? You need the current task.

Comment: Yes, and I want get index dynamically instead of [0]. I can"t get that index

Comment: I think you need a component. Look at https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-html-editor

Comment: Thank you for link I try to use this component in my todo list and give feedback

Comment: the [library](https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-html-editor) you mentioned looks abandoned because it only works with vue-1. It is not only specified in the description, but I also looked into the source code, and hereb I confirm it would not work on Vue 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the preferred approach would be to build a component (or use [an existing one](https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-html-editor)), which would have props, etc. However, it turns out that there is an internal property of `this` inside the directive that you can use: `_scope`. It is documented (well, mentioned at least) in the [terminal directive example](https://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#terminal).

Your bind function becomes:

```
bind: function() {
  const scope = this._scope;
  this.editor = $(this.el).summernote({
    airMode: true,
    disableDragAndDrop: true,
    popover: {
      air: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']]
      ]
    },
    callbacks: {
      onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
        scope.task.title = contents;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I change my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vborshchov/f5Lhaw2e/23/) to show task title `onInit` summernote callback

Comment: the library connecting vue to summernote looks abandoned because it only works with vue-1. It is not only specified in the description, but I also looked into the source code, and hereb I confirm it would not work on Vue 2

Comment: https://github.com/cho0o0/vuejs2-summernote-component might be useful